# Most efficient way to call method on all combinations from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list of item, each with a method that takes any other item as a parameter. What would be the most efficient way of ensuring that I call the method on every possible pair of items, without repeating them? (All items can be assumed to be unique).

My code:

```
public boolean hasConflict (ArrayList<Item> items) {
    // For every possible pair of items...
        one = items.get(i);
        two = items.get(j);

        if ( one.conflictsWith (two)) {
            return true;
        }

    // If we reach the end of the list without finding a conflict
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

`one.conflictsWith (two)` will return the same value as `two.conflictsWith (one)`, apologies for forgetting that.

The `conflictsWith` method isn't comparing to see if the two values are duplicate, so unfortunately I can't use a hash table to sort it out.

Comment: Does one.conflictsWith(two) return the same as two.conflictsWith(one) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple if you don't need to call `a.conflictsWith(b)` as well as `b.conflictsWith(a)` you can save some time by doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    final MyClass curr = list.get(i);
    for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); ++j) {
        curr.conflictsWith(list.get(j));
    }
}
```

i.e. loop over the `List` and then, in a second loop, loop over **the remainder** of the `List`.

Otherwise you need to loop over *everything*

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    final MyClass curr = list.get(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); ++j) {
        if(i != j) {
            curr.conflictsWith(list.get(j));
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: don't think this will cover all combinations. if i = 10 combinations like (10,0) would never get executed

Comment: @DevBlanked have added a more thorough explanation.

Comment: In your symmetric case, You also need that a.conflictWith(a) is always false.

Answer (score 1):

If `conflictsWith()` is symmetric, i.e. `one.conflictsWith(two) == two.conflictsWith(one)` for every pair of arguments, then use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
{
    final Item one = items.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < items.size(); j++}
    {
        one.conflictsWith(items.get(j));
    }
}
```

If it is not symmetric, you have to check 2x more:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
{
    final Item one = items.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++} // only this line changed
    {
        one.conflictsWith(items.get(j));
    }
}
```

The last one will also check `one.conflictsWith(one)`. If that's a problem, use          `if (i != j)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not know what "conflict" means, i.e. if for example `a.conflictsWith(b)` and `a. conflictsWith(c)` says s.th about `b.conflictsWith(c)`, you have to touch every combination, that i.e.

```
   for(int i=0; i< items.size(); i++) {
     Item item = items.get(i);
     for(int j=0; j< items.size(); j++)
       if(item.conflictsWith(items.get(j)) return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
```

If the relation conflictWith is symmetric and if a.conflictsWith(a) is always false you can use

```
   for(int i=0; i< items.size(); i++) {
     Item item = items.get(i);
     for(int j=i+1; j< items.size(); j++)
       if(item.conflictsWith(items.get(j)) return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
```